# Login mysql on gitpod

Tags: mysql, gitpod

I started a fresh project using gitpod.
I did the regular npm init and I'm using express, hbs.
On my terminal, when I entered "mysql -u root"
It says "bash: mysql: command not found"

Comment: I've also tried yarn add mysql after that. It couldn't work either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to install mysql first. Try using a [custom docker image](https://www.gitpod.io/docs/config-docker) - [gitpod/workspace-mysql](https://github.com/gitpod-io/workspace-images/tree/master/mysql)

File: `.gitpod.yml`

```yaml
image:
  file: .gitpod.dockerfile
```

File: `.gitpod.dockerfile`

```
FROM gitpod/workspace-mysql
```

You'll likely need to create a user with a password for your application to connect.

```sh
mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE my_db;"
mysql -e "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root_password';"
```